# Extracting indices from numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy

I want the last 4 values of this equation.

Is there a better way to this in one step, like modifying the equation or another extraction technique other than using `delete`

```
a=5
d=2

n = np.cumsum(d ** np.arange(1, a+1))
print 'n=', n
n = np.delete(n,0)
print 'n extracted=', n

n= [ 2  6 14 30 62]
n extracted= [ 6 14 30 62]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print n[-4::]
```

will print the last 4 elements. You can do all kinds of array slicing like this, the above was just an example. You can index the array from the front or the back.

Comment: you should note that in this case the second `:` is optional

Comment: Then that would mean I can also do this `n = n[1:]` Which way is more efficient in terms of performance slicing or deleting.

Comment: @user3084006 Is this the actual use case or is this a simplified example? I mean, do you always just have to remove the first element out of a 5 element list? Or will you have to remove 50 elements from a 20000 element list (for example)?

Comment: @Cyber it is a simplified case. I am just trying to remove x elements out something like `n=n[len(n)-x,:]`, `n = np.delete(n,index), index=[x]`